# jQuery Autocomplete Remote

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I'm using this http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote on my website, I can see this code 'searches' search.php does anyone know what format search.php should be in and what it should look like?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the page you linked, it shows you the expected data format. (pasted below) At it's simplest, you can have a print statement in the search.php file that simply echoes back some hard coded contents. A more elaborate solution is to have your search.php pull real time from a database and then format the data as expected.

```
Expected data format

The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two variants:

An Array of Strings:
[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

So, just to get off the ground and see it working, use this line for search.php and build from there by customizing your choices or connecting to a db etc.

```
print '[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]';
```